# 'Accidental' Exponentials

Tags: roblox, exponential

(Solved, however I would love to know WHY this happens.)

So,I have this script which should make a huge block of "brick" parts. The idea was for something like breaking them in some way (first thought was an archery range...)

Bricks originally 2x2x2, now 4x4x4 due to performance of parts. Mostly because this is a rather stupid idea when at this scale lol.
However when i changed that, it also broke the script exponentially on the Y axis

```
-- Origin == {POS = 0,0,0; SIZE = 4,4,4}
-- Finality == {POS == -477, 2, 243; SIZE = 4,4,4}

local location   =   {X = script.Origin.Position.X, 
                  Y = script.Origin.Position.Y, 
                  Ymoved = script.Origin.Position.Y,
                  Z = script.Origin.Position.Z}
--[[Previously Ymoved started at Origin.Position and went up how many tiles we went per floor.]]


local MATZ          = {"Marble","Ice"}
local Colours       = {Color3.new(0.25, 0.25, 0.25),Color3.new(0.811765, 0.992157, 1)}
local locationEnd   = script.Finality.Position
local count             = 0

local Vector = Vector3.new

while true do
    local brick = Instance.new("Part", game.Workspace)

        --Main Part creation
    brick.Name          = "Brick_"..count
    brick.Position      = Vector(location.X, location.Y, location.Z)
    brick.Size          = Vector(4,4,4)
    brick.Anchored      = true

        --Prettify (needs more options)
    local SEED          = math.random(1,2)
    brick.Material      = MATZ[SEED]
    brick.Color         = Colours[SEED]
    
    if location == locationEnd then 
                --unsafe, needs to be changed once i actually have an endpoint...
        break
    
    elseif location.X >= locationEnd.X then
        location.X = script.Origin.Position.X
        location.Z = location.Z - 4
        print("Next column")

    elseif location.Z <= locationEnd.Z then
        location.X = script.Origin.Position.X
        location.Z = script.Origin.Position.Z

                location.Ymoved = location.Ymoved + 2
        location.Y = script.Origin.Position.Y + location.Ymoved    --This line is antibepis
        print("Next floor")
    end
    
    if count % 250 == 0 then
        wait()
    end
    

    location.X = location.X + 4
    count = count + 1
end
```

Inevitably, after noticing the problem was on the Y axis, thought that i should look into how the script changes Y values.

Thus:

```
location.Ymoved = location.Ymoved + 2
location.Y = script.Origin.Position.Y + location.Ymoved
```

This section of code is all that had broken.

When written as above, it will produce parts exponentially closer together

```
location.Ymoved = location.Ymoved + 2
location.Y = location.Y + location.Ymoved
```

However when changed this, every layer is placed exponentially farther away...
Eventually i remembered to kiss* it, which resulted in the following. (*Keep it simple, stupid)

```
location.Y = location.Y + 4
```

This, is technically the actual solution to prevent the strange exponentials
However, *why* do the exponentials happen? These stripes don't occur when the block size is 2x2x2... Whats the difference? (As my brain is too fried from fixing this to see it lol)

Answer (score 0):

If you generate 4 stud high blocks every 2 studs, they will overlap. If you generate 2 stud high blocks every 2 studs, they will align nicely.

In the diagram, both stacks of boxes have their position increased by 2 each time. It aligns perfectly for the 2x2 stack, but the boxes overlap for the 4x4 stack.
[image]